# Estimating discretization step from noisy timeseries

Tags: time-series, discrete-data

We have a sensor that measures some physical process. As the sensor discretize the data, when reading the signal we should only see the value in discrete steps. For example, when the signal varies from 200 to 400, we will not see all possible values between 200 and 400, but rather values like `200 225 250 ... 375 400` indicating the discretization step of 25.

However our signal reader is also noisy resulting in values like `198 224 261 275` etc. How does one estimate the discretization step from the data? This knowledge will allow to filter the noise better based on very few past points which is important as the value is used in the control system.

I suppose one cannot do the estimation  without some ideas about the noise and its distribution should be assumed. But then if one assumes some distribution, what is the correct way to estimate the step?

My initial thinking was just to enumerate all the possible steps, then for each step calculate reminders of values divided by the step. Then the discretization step should be one when the remainders produce the best fit to the chosen distribution.

But then I realized that the discretization step is not an integer. The sender uses PWM to encode the data so its step depends on the frequency of its clock which does not match the   the frequency of the decoder.

I suppose I can try the least square method to fit both the parameters of the distribution and the step, but how then one expresses the reminder function?

In our case a typical histogram of data points from a single run is given bellow.

```
value   count
682     2
775     8
776     14
807     7
838     3
868     1
869     2
900     1
931     3
993     2
1024    2
1055    2
1117    3
1179    2
1210    1
1241    1
1272    2
1303    1
1334    1
1365    2
1397    1
1427    1
1428    2
1458    1
1521    2
1551    1
1552    1
1583    1
1614    1
1645    1
1676    1
1707    3
1738    1
1769    1
1800    2
1831    1
1862    3
1893    1
1924    2
1955    1
1986    2
2047    1
2048    2
2079    1
2111    1
2141    1
2142    1
2173    1
2204    2
2234    1
2235    2
2266    1
2297    1
2325    1
2359    2
2390    3
2483    3
2514    2
2545    1
2575    1
2607    2
2638    3
2669    1
2731    4
2762    2
2794    2
2823    1
2825    1
2854    1
2858    1
2889    1
2918    2
2980    3
3011    2
3042    2
3071    1
3073    1
3104    2
3134    2
3135    1
3197    3
3228    1
3259    1
3287    1
3289    1
3290    2
3321    2
3351    1
3352    2
3383    1
3414    1
3445    4
3506    1
3508    3
3539    1
3570    3
3601    2
3630    1
3632    1
3661    1
3663    2
3694    2
3723    1
3725    2
3754    2
3756    2
3785    16
3787    7
3818    45
3820    1
3822    1
3825    2
3849    3
3880    2
3911    1
3942    3
3971    1
3973    2
4002    1
4004    2
4035    5
4095    1
4097    3
4128    2
4152    1
4157    2
4191    2
4220    1
4222    1
4251    1
4253    3
4276    1
4313    1
4315    4
4344    1
4346    3
4375    3
4377    4
```

Comment: Nice problem, is this an actual real-life issue or a homework problem? And to be clear, you want to infer the latent discretization step of the left-hand column above, right? Because you don't mention the counts in the question.

Comment: The sensor measures the position of a hydraulic actuator. The reason for repeated counts is that the actuator sits mostly still modulo vibrations but then move back and forward. Presently to filter out PWM  noise we use the median of the last 10 values. But that adds latency. So we investigate if better modeling can reduce that to 2-3 points so the system react faster and we do need to replace the board with one with a better PWM reader.